# ExtJs4 - how to run and make first MVC template in Sencha Command?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-command

I'm trying to run 'Sencha Command' from http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/ SDK on windows, but i just don't know what to do.

How to run and make first ExtJs4 MVC template in Sencha Command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if the current preview release (PR5) even contains the **Sencha Command** command line tools. There is quite some stuff still missing in the current ExtJS 4 PR5 download so I would not be surprised if the command line component is still missing.

**EDIT**

Just checked the sources of ExtJS 4 PR5 and there currently is no **Sencha Command** command line interface.

Comment: Yep.. it's true.. but there is a "Sencha Touch" command line tool.. and as i get i can use it to generato some ExtJs4 template? or not?

Comment: Never tried. The ExtJS command line tool and the MVC architecture will be based on what we currently have for Sencha Touch but I don't know if they are that compatible. I even have not seen any traces of the MVC component itself within ExtJS 4 PR5 such as `Ext.Application`. So to my conclusion the current PR5 lacks still lacks all those MVC application stuff.